# How to loop from one column cell to another cell in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL. I have a column consisting of dates. I have to loop through the entire column accessing each date, Can someone please provide me with the syntax of the `for/while loop` to accomplish this?

The dates are not consecutive.
I am using PHP

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense - SQL doesn't have for/while loops. Closing.

Comment: why do you need to loop through them and what have you tried?

Comment: SQL returns tabular data in most instances.  As such it doesn't do the looping. That is controlled by the User Interface.  What are you trying to display results in? PHP? .Net? Other?  It's that application where you would "loop"  Maybe you need to loop though it in a package or procedure though...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 'table'`, loop through them in your connector, may this be PHP, C#, C++ or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL itself doesn't have a for/while loop. It's a database connection, and if you've got a database consistent of an amount of rows, you can SELECT them.

You would use your connector(.NET/PHP, or a third language?), to connect and handle this data.

This could be a PHP example, using the built in MySQLi module.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT dateCol from table";
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["dateCol"];
    } 
?>
```